# Demonstration in probability theory involving limits and sets

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, probability-theory

I am taking a probability theory lecture, and I am really stuck with one of the exercises

[Here is the exercise I will be speaking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIhUC.png)

I thoroughly went through the theory, I read many other sources on internet, and I think that I have now an understanding of sequences, limits, set theory, and probability theory that should be enough to understand this problem - I mean, there are some strong gaps between my knowledge in mathematics and the requirement for that lecture, but I already spend like two full days on it, so I think it is enough (I am not complaining though, just I do not know where to look anymore).

When I read the information of the problem, I understand them. I mean, I understand what is happening, what each term represents, and why that term is equal to that other one.

My problem reguards the demonstration:

- (A): $\lim\sup_{n\rightarrow\infty} A_n = \{\omega \in \Omega : \omega \in A_n \text{ for infinitely many values of n}\}$
- (B): $\lim\inf_{n\rightarrow\infty} A_n = \{\omega \in \Omega : \omega \in A_n \text{ for all but finitely many values of n}\}$

I think one of the problem is that I do not really understand what these two last sentences mean:

- I understand the sentences "for infinitely many values" and "for all but finitely many values".
- I do not know how to represent myself the set $\{\omega \in \Omega : \omega \in A_n \text{ for infinitely many values of n}\}$
- I do not know how to represent myself the set $\{\omega \in \Omega : \omega \in A_n \text{ for all but finitely many values of n}\}$

Additionally, I have no clue on how I should demonstrate something containing these sentences, and I do not see the link between the sample space $\Omega$, the outcomes $\omega$, and the information provided at the begining of the problem. But, maybe, this would become clearer once I have a better understanding of what those sets are.

I am not asking that someone do it for me. I want to have a hint on where to start, and what would be the underlying idea for that demonstration.

Comment: See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_limit#The_two_definitions)

Comment: A more explicit definition is given by
\begin{align}
\limsup_{n\to\infty} A_n &= \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\bigcup_{k=n}^\infty A_k\\
\liminf_{n\to\infty} A_n &= \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\bigcap_{k=n}^\infty A_k.
\end{align}